# Windows 10 UDP buffer size / Multicast receiving

Tags: java, windows, networking, buffer, multicast

I have a java client that listens to multicast (which is sent by a java server). I have the socket buffer on the receive side set to around 10 megabytes. Currently the receiver is on both a linux system and a windows system. I was having problems with dropping packets at the OS level, but realized that the receive buffer was to small. I was able to fix this very easily on linux by upping the values in

```
sysctl net.core.rmem_max
sysctl net.core.rmem_default
```

However, I can not seem to get the same results with windows. I tried upping the `DefaultReceiveWindow` in `ADP/Parameters` in the registry keys and tried maxing out the buffer settings on the network card. Neither of those settings worked, and I am still dropping a lot of packets on the client-side in windows.

I have confirmed via pcap capturing that it is not my application that is dropping the packets since the pcap files do not produce the packets either. Are there other settings that I am not setting correctly in windows? Something else I should check to verify that windows is in fact dropping the packets?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the CPU/Network/Memory usage on the windows task manager? Also can you estimate the percentage of packets received by the receiver? For example, the receiver receive 30% of the packets?